# ordering json in python mapping object

Tags: python, json, object, mapping, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch where the query is to be posted in json and should be in standard order or else the result will be wrong. the problem is that the python is changing my json ordering. my original json query is.

```
x= {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*a*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "city": "london"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "industry.industry_not_analyed": "oil"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "industry": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "industry.industry_not_analyed"
      }
    },
    "city": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city.city_not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the resulting python object is as follow.

```
{
  'query': {
    'filtered': {
      'filter': {
        'and': {
          'filters': [
            {
              'term': {
                'city': 'london'
              }
            },
            {
              'term': {
                'industry.industry_not_analyed': 'oil'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      'query': {
        'query_string': {
          'query': '*a*'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'facets': {
    'city': {
      'terms': {
        'field': 'city.city_not_analyzed'
      }
    },
    'industry': {
      'terms': {
        'field': 'industry.industry_not_analyed'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result is different than what I need how do I solve this.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: my python version is 2.7.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python dictionary, keep keys/values in same order as declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: the output is right i had made up a complete mess with some other part of my program. ordering in json doesent matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [OrderedDict()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of `{}`. Note that you can't simply use `OrderedDict(query=...)` because that would create an unordered dict in the background. Use this code instead:

```
x = OrderedDict()
x['query'] = OrderedDict()
...
```

I suggest to implement a builder for this:

```
x = Query().filtered().query_string("*a*").and()....
```

Comment: can you please help me how to frame the complete query with OrderedDict()

Comment: Write a unit test for this and build the query step by step until the output is exactly as you want it.

Comment: i thank you for you interest and your afford but i am unable to figure how to write the query


a={
 "a":"a",
 "b":"b"
}
print a

b={}
b['a']="a"
b['b']="b"
print b

c=collections.OrderedDict()
c['a']="a"
c['b']="b"
print c

output:
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
OrderedDict([('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')])

please help me how to figure out the way to write the query